# how to get oauth token from bing without user interaction in php

Tags: php

I am using Bing ads API. They have given an official example at

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f

In reportrequests.php, it asks for auhthentication token:

```
$proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, null, null, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, $CustomerId, "AuthenticationTokenGoesHere");
```

How do I get it without any user interaction?I tried following steps at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632721.aspx

Could I please get a direction here. The example above seems to add a little though very verbose.